# How to select all checkboxes at Facebook's Publishing Tools page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook

I have a facebook page and I need delete all posts but I can't because those too many posts.
I want select all checkboxes with js with console.
Example;

```
<div class="_88ly"><input aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" id="js_2mg" class="" type="checkbox"><div class="_7bwf" style="box-shadow: none; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); height: 24px; min-height: 24px; min-width: 24px; width: 24px; border-radius: 6px;"><i class="_7r2j img sp_AmPUyaXuSMx sx_6cfb9e" height="16" width="16" alt="" data-visualcompletion="css-img" style="opacity: 1;"></i></div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to use jQuery, you have this functionality: https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

`$( ":checkbox" ), or $( "[type=checkbox]" )` will let you select elements that are of type checkbox. That seems from the minimal code provided to be what you're looking for